# Visibility_notify event in pyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk

I am on windows and I am developing a pygtk app. I need to know when a window is visible or hidden by another window. In order to stop an heavy drawing process.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--visibility-notify-event

I Use the visibility_notify_event to be notified on windows visibility state change.
I should get gtk.gdk.VISIBILITY_FULLY_OBSCURED, gtk.gdk.VISIBILITY_PARTIAL or gtk.gdk.VISIBILITY_UNOBSCURED

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkevent.html

here is a sample that display message when event occured.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class EventBoxExample:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Test")
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.set_border_width(10)

        # Create an EventBox and add it to our toplevel window
        self.event_box = gtk.EventBox()

        window.add(self.event_box)        
        self.event_box.show()

        #we want all events
        self.event_box.set_events(gtk.gdk.ALL_EVENTS_MASK)

        #connect events
        self.event_box.connect ("map_event", self.Map)
        self.event_box.connect ("unmap_event", self.unMap)
        self.event_box.connect ("configure_event", self.Configure)
        self.event_box.connect ("expose_event", self.Expose)
        self.event_box.connect ("visibility_notify_event", self.Visibility)
        self.event_box.connect ("key_press_event", self.KeyPress)
        self.event_box.connect ("button_press_event", self.ButtonPress)
        self.event_box.connect ("button_release_event", self.ButtonRelease)
        self.event_box.connect ("motion_notify_event", self.MouseMotion)
        self.event_box.connect ("destroy", self.Destroy) 
        self.event_box.connect ("enter_notify_event", self.Enter)
        self.event_box.connect ("leave_notify_event", self.Leave)
        self.event_box.connect ("delete_event", self.Destroy)

        window.show()

    def Map (self, *args):
        print "Map ", args        
        return True

    def unMap (self, *args):
        print "unMap ", args        
        return True

    def Configure (self, *args):
        print "Configure"
        return True

    def Expose (self, *args):
        print "Expose"
        return True

    def Visibility (self, *args):
        print "Visibility"
        return True

    def KeyPress (self, *args):
        print "KeyPress"
        return True

    def ButtonPress (self, *args):
        print "ButtonPress"
        return True

    def ButtonRelease (self, *args):
        print "ButtonRelease"
        return True

    def MouseMotion (self, *args):
        print "MouseMotion"
        return True

    def Enter (self, *args):
        print "Enter"
        self.event_box.grab_focus ()
        return True

    def Leave (self, *args):
        print "Leave"
        return True

    def Destroy (self, *args):
        print "Destroy"

def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    EventBoxExample()
    main()
```

Does any one has any idea of why I can't get visibility_notify_event?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite likely that the underlying GDK layer simply isn't "good enough" on Windows. The GTK+ toolkit's port to Windows is known to be a bit lagging in functionality and polish.

If you can try the same program on a Linux machine, and it works there, you can be pretty certain this is a limitation of the Windows port.

Comment: tried on linux by a friend and he got the visibility event. You are right it's seems to not be implemented on windows port thx